# SDL2, X11, No Desktop Environment: application without focus, no input events

Tags: x11, sdl-2, xorg

I have an SDL application that correctly works in fullscreen if launched from command line on a Raspberry Pi that doesn't have a Desktop Environment with this command:

```
/path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2
```

If I launch the application with xinit, using .xinitrc with application path and its parameters inside, the application normally starts but I can't get keyboard and mouse events.

I can't get a way in order to have my application focused (I think this is the problem), have you any idea?

**Content of .xinitrc:**

```
/path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2
```

that I launch from command line with this command:

```
xinit
```

Comment: Could you explain how you launch it when it "works"? If it don't have desktop environment (window manager, more specifically), how do you launch it? To get desired behaviour I suppose you'll have to either use any window manager or try something like `XSetInputFocus` call when your window is ready.

Comment: I have a command line in front of me when system starts (i.e. Raspberry Pi OS Lite) and, as I wrote in the opening post, I launch the application with `/path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2`. How can I use `XSetInputFocus` in SDL2 application?

Comment: You'll need to get X11-specific window descriptor of your SDL window. I've never done that without window manager so no idea if it'd actually work. Why not just launch some very thin WM instead? E.g. install openbox and use `openbox & /path_to_my_app/myapp -parameter1 -parameter2 value_for_parameter_2` as your startup scrpt.

Comment: It works but I have the mouse pointer visible and a poor performance (it is an emulator and I got 15 FPS instead of 60). I don't know if it is related to poor x11 driver performance with SDL versus KMSDRM driver. Any idea?

Comment: You can hide cursor with `SDL_ShowCursor(0)`. As for performance - non-compositing window manager (which openbox is) should not add any noticable performance penalty. You have it running on the same hardware in 60fps w/o X? Why do you need X in the first place then? I don't know what your code is, can't say anything aside generic check if hardware acceleration is available with `glxinfo`, verify which SDL renderer backend is used if you use SDL renderer (`SDL_GetRendererInfo`), run in profiler and see if anything stands out.

Comment: Already hide, in my code there is a `SDL_ShowCursor(SDL_DISABLE);` and YES, without x11, using KMSDRM driver, the emulator runs at 60 FPS. I need X only for checking the coordinates of different connected mouses. Now I'm trying to avoid this reading from `/dev/input/event*` but I got a segfault (maybe because we need root?)